# Create a discrete distribution from transformed container elements

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

Suppose we have a `std::vector<T> v` and `T` is a class with a member function `U T::f() const`, where `U` is convertible to `double`. I want to create a `std::discrete_distribution<> d(/* v[0].f(), ..., v[v.size() - 1].f() */)`. Is this possible without creating a new container containing the values `v[0].f(), ..., v[v.size() - 1].f()`?

Comment: `transform_iterator` (from boost or range library).

Comment: If you could make a [transformation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) [iterator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155866/preprocessing-iterator) `tit`, you could use `d(tit, end(v))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) can do that. You'll just need to create those from the vector's iterators.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a `operator double` to `T` then you can have that return `f()` and then use the iterator constructor of `std::discrete_distribution` like

```
struct Foo
{
    operator double() const { return f(); }
    double f() const { return 1.0; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foo(10);
    std::discrete_distribution dd{foo.begin(), foo.end()};
}
```